# Use Access Token once accepted?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am currently trying to develop a GAE application.

I followed this tutorial in order to get access to gdocs using OAuth. 
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html

What I can't understand is how to reuse this token afterwards.

If I directly try to access feeds on a second connection, I got bounced due to a lack of authorization (401). 
I think I have to authenticate each time using the access_token in my Gdocs object, but can't find the right way to do it.

Any ideas?

My code is the same as in the tutorial, plus:

```
# Create an instance of the DocsService to make API calls
gdocs = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source = SETTINGS['APP_NAME'])

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
@login_required
def get(self):
    my_user = users.get_current_user()

    # I think I have to authenticate, but don't know how here 
    token_key = 'access_token_%s' % my_user.user_id()
    access_token = gdata.gauth.ae_load(token_key)
    gdocs.auth_token = gdocs.get_access_token(access_token)

    feed = gdocs.GetResources()
    for entry in feed.entry:
        template = '<div>%s</div>'
        self.response.out.write(template % entry.title.text)
```

Which is launched by default.

I know I have access to the token key using ae_load(token_key), as I can print it.
Should I use gdocs to authenticate, or a more general client, as I is shown here :
http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/

I checked and my token is listed in my private google account.

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally answered my own question by searching in google apis.

Here is how I use it :

```
    access_token_key = 'access_token_%s' % user.user_id()
    access_token = gdata.gauth.ae_load(access_token_key)       
    # authenticating here
    #gdocs.auth_token = access_token
```

Another version could be this :

```
    #gdocs.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuthHmacToken(SETTINGS['CONSUMER_KEY'], 
    #                                               SETTINGS['CONSUMER_SECRET'], 
    #                                               access_token,
    #                                               access_token_key, 
    #                                               gdata.gauth.ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

as states google 's doc.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the auth_token, or data to reconstruct it in the datastore.  Then when creating your request objects, pass the auth_token in.  This is explained within the GDClient [doc string](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/client.py#152).

You might also find the article on [fetching gdata feeds](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the second link exactly corresponds to my code as I said. What was missing is the next step.